# Mesh analysis of circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, network, mesh-analysis

In this question we are required to find the nodal voltages and current in the circuit.

[image]

Why is the 3A current not divided at node (d), that is, one going in 5 ohm resistor and other towards the source. The loop equation is given as:

[image]

Comment: The 3 A current *does* divide at node **d**. However, the whole point of mesh analysis is to assume pseudo-currents (the word `pseudo` is just for your mental use so that you recognize it's not necessarily the same as final resulting device currents) in order to develop voltage drops around the loop which must sum to zero according to KVL. These `pseudo` currents add up (relative signs according to relative directions) in parts that share two loop currents, for example. I've not looked at your equations, though. Just saying something about your node **d** question, is all.

Comment: The 3 A loop current is a `pseudo`-current for that loop (it is also an actual current for the current source -- an accidental coincidence here) and you treat it as if it did *not* divide up. The simultaneous use of KVL on the three loops will work out in the end and will tell you how it actually divides up. But before that moment where you have the full answer, you treat them as though they run around the loop without dividing up. When you get i1 you will know how much of i3 actually goes through the 5 Ohm resistor and how much through the 12 V source. But you won't know until you get i1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHcvUJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Consider an electrical network made up only of resistors, independent voltage and current generators. It turns out that the presence of current generators makes the direct application of the mesh-based analysis method impossible because the auxiliary variables, i.e. the co-tree currents aren't sufficient to express the voltages at the terminals of each current generator given that the voltage at the ends of these generators is independent of the current passing through them and therefore
must be considered an unknown quantity. So the unknowns are: the auxiliary variables and the voltages at the terminals of the current generators. To this increase in the number of the unknowns, corresponds an equal increase in the number of equations, as each current generator introduces a constraint between the currents and therefore a new equation.

[image]

Comment: For material copied from another source we need to see a link to the original source or at least a citation for it. Can you add that, please?

Comment: The two graphs, i.e. the circuit provided by the person who published the post and the oriented graph with independent meshes, were created by me with Windows Paint , as well as calculations. The theory, however, can be traced back to the text from the nineties, "Fondamenti di Elettrotecnica" Volume one, Second edition; authors: "G. Martinelli, M. Salerno" Editrice Siderea.